# MYSQL select con varias condiciones

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría hacer un select en mi base de datos como el siguiente:

BBDD:

```
marca modelo coche
audi   a1     si
audi   a1     si
audi   a1     si
audi   a1     si
bmw    x4     si
bmw    x4     si
bmw    x4     si
opel   s5     no
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT count(coche = "Si") as nr FROM formulario where marca= "Audi";
```

El output de este es 4, por ejemplo, pero me gustaría obtener tambien el numero de otros coches, algo así:

```
SELECT count(coche = "Si") as nr FROM formulario where marca= "Audi","BMW";
```

Con un output así: `[4, 3]`

Esto lo necesito para una consulta php en mi base de datos. Como podría hacerlo? Gracias!

Comment: Por favor debes proveer un mejor contexto de tu pregunta, recomiendo edites y coloques un [mcve]

Comment: Podrías agregarle operadores lógicos al where

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo la base de datos, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo contando en una sub-consulta, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.total) 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM formulari 
      WHERE marca IN("Audi","BMW") 
      GROUP BY marca
      ORDER BY marca
     ) AS t;
```

Esta consulta te traerá el total de cada marca, ordenado por marca, o sea, que el primer total será de `Audi` y el segundo será de `BMW`  y así...

Si quieres algo más completo, puedes agregar identificadores en el resultado, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('marca:',t.marca),' total:',t.total) 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT MAX(marca) AS marca, COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM formulari 
      WHERE marca IN("Audi","BMW") 
      GROUP BY marca
      ORDER BY marca
     ) AS t;
```

Esto te traerá algo así: `"Audi: N, BMV: N"`, donde `N` será el total de cada marca.